# Why does U+E006 (  ) show as a t-shirt on iOS?

Tags: ios, unicode, utf-8

My website imports a lot of business data from an external source I've no control over. Among those, I'm importing the character U+E006

When I echo this in my page:

- Linux+Windows+Mac+Android: garbage
- iOS: a T-Shirt

[See it here with an iOS device](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e006/browsertest.htm)

FileFormat.info [reports](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e006/index.htm) that this is not a valid UTF-8 char.

What's going on? Is U+E006 valid UTF-8 or not? If, as i suspect, it isn't actually valid, why the iOS behaviour?

Comment: U+E006 is a *code point*, not UTF-8. The UTF-8 sequence for it is the bytes EE 80 86. Unicode and Unicode *transformations* (UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32) are not the same thing, more: http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Unicode range U+E000-U+F8FF is a [private use](https://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html) range, so anyone can do what they want with it. Apple decided to put some emojis there it seems.

Also note that Unicode and UTF-8 aren’t the same thing. It’s an undefined Unicode character, but it doesn’t say anything about if the byte sequence would be valid UTF-8 or not.

Comment: Well, it's defined in some sense -- as a private use character. :-) https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=E006

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If we’re splitting hairs, it’s an undefined _character_ still. It’s just not an undefined _code point_ since it’s defined as private use ;)